# Why the error getting when importing table data from Oracle DB to HIVE using Sqoop?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am getting below error while importing data from oracle DB to HIVE using Sqoop

ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=2, No such file or directory

below is my command which I am executing.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/xe--username sa --    password sa --table SA.SHIVAMSAMPLE --hive-import -m 1

The data is getting created inside hdfs but hive tables are not getting created i.e a folder gets created inside (bin/hdfs dfs -ls) direct default directory.
when I will give explicitly path for warehouse then only it will store in warehouse directory like "user/hive/warehouse" after that also table not created and not loaded data.

I installed hadoop in "Amit/hadoop-2.6.5" and HIVe is "Amit/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin" and sqoop "Amit/sqoop-1.4.5-cdh5.3.2" in .bashrc I set the hadoop path only.
Is require to hive and sqoop as well.

When I set hive home in sqoop-env.sh file then above command run fine but table is not created and file is created inside hdfs /user/hive/warehouse/shivamsample
can you please tell me any extra conf require to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sqoop is unable to find hive, have you set your **$HIVE_HOME** environment variable? You can either set that or use **--hive-home** in your sqoop command and point it to the root directory of your hive installation

Comment: After adding home path of hive in Sqoop-env.sh. Command complete without error but not able to see Table  in HIVE when running query "select * from SHIVAMSAMPLE". when again running same command so getting error :table already exist.

Comment: You can add --hive-overwrite if you want it to overwrite the table if it exists. As far are your query, you need to add the database -> "select * from sa.shivamsample".

Comment: "select * from SA.SHIVAMSAMPLE;" still same issue .In hdfs SA.SHIVAMSAMPLE is created in "hdfs -ls" default directory not in warehouse directory.
Run below sqoop command which is  SA.SHIVAMSAMPLE  created  inside warehouse directory.But in hive not able to find the table."bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/xe --username sa --password sa --table SA.SHIVAMSAMPLE --hive-table new22 --create-hive-table --hive-import -m 1"

Comment: If you haven't already created an external Hive table you need to add **--create-hive-table** to your sqoop-import command.

Comment: yes I haven`t created external table that`s why I put  --create-hive-table in command,after that also not able to see the table in HIVE.Is any path conf missing .because command put file inside "user/hive/warehouse" and I am running hive from its installed path "Amit/Hive>bin/hive"

Comment: Try to specify the database and table like this: **--hive-database sa --hive-table shivamsample**

Comment: I tried and change command as below and created database "sa" in hive it giving error Database "sa" does not exist                                                    
 "bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@illin4549:1521/zigcrm45 --username sa --password sa --table SA.SHIVAMSAMPLE --hive-import --hive-database sa --hive-table shivamsample -m 1"                                                                                in HIve shell output is below                                                                                                  hive> show databases;
default
sa